# How do I get past the "hemispherical depression?

Tags: amnesia-the-dark-descent

I'm in the Chancel, having just met Agrippa in the area before. There's a Hemispherical Deression and an Orb the game keeps ranting about, but nothing I can seem to do about it. There's an altar I can't do anything to, some levers I can't pull, a door I can't open and a tunnel full of electricity I can't pass, right next to the hemispherical depression. I can pour some tar in the depression and that's about it, but nothing seems to change.

What do I do here? I'm clearly supposed to find some orb, but where and how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Near Agrippa, there is a trapdoor in the ceiling that you can open. You can hear the sound of moving machinery coming from it. Find something to stand on to reach it.

[image: Trapdoor in the ceiling]

Inside, you will see some gears and you have to slide one of them into contact with the others. This enables the levers which you can then use to open up access to two new areas where you can find the pieces of the orb.